# AngularJS Reload Function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

It logs in but does not automatically refresh the page.

`login.php` Angular Code:

```
var app = angular.module("Test", []);
app.controller("Logintest", function($scope, $http){
  $scope.Login = function(){
    $http({
      method:"POST",
      url:"login-control.php",
      data:$scope.loginData
    }).then(function(response){
      if(response.data != '') {
        $scope.RESULT = response.data;
      } else {
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

`login.php` PHP code:

```php
if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])) {
 ( HTML FORM CODE ) 
} else {
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Sending back a redirect from your AJAX call does not redirect your whole page, only that single HTTP request made via AJAX.

Comment: this works in another code. but I can't redirect in my own code, what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems using php `header()` as well, but you can use plain javascript for it:
**Note:** Just because you are using Angular doesn't mean that plain javascript is blocked for use.

```js
var wl = window.location;
window.location = wl;
```

Or if you **need** to use php, just echo the JS in a script:

```
<?php
  echo "<script>var wl = window.location; window.location = wl;";
?>
```